# Any way to know which Content Area was included?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, ampscript

I'm using AMPScript in an email to do lookups and decide which content area to include.

Is there any way to know which content area was included for each recipient? Ideally I'd like to pull this info via the REST API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  [Impression Regions](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/impression_tracking/) will track that information, however there's not a lot of retrievable data available, other than the two canned reports.

The Impression Region name cannot be an AMPScript variable.

I believe support has to enable the canned reports.

If you'd rather have some more flexibility, you can build it yourself using AMPScript variables and the [Send Log](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/send_logging/).  Basically, you determine what version of the email the subscriber is getting, set a variable like `@emailCode`, and then enable Send Logging on the send.  If you have an `emailCode` column in your Send Log, then it'll get recorded.  Then it's accessible via Query Activity and API.  Send Logging has to be enabled by SFMC Support.

Comment: Send Log definitely looks like it'll work. If we don't have either of these things enabled now, is there any way to extract this info for already-sent emails?

Comment: No.  You have to have the Impression Region AMPScript in your emails for the data to be aggregated.

Comment: Ok, got it. And if we do add impression regions to the code, is there any way to extract that data via the API as is? Or do we need to use Send Logging for that?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to extract it via API directly.  You can get the data in a file with a Tracking Data Extract.  Technically you can create that Extract and execute it via API, but the end result is a file.

Comment: Tracking Extract is definitely a bit hacky, but it'll work. Thanks for your help!